# How to use activities in a swipe views with tabs

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, swipe

In one app, I would like to use three activities with a swipe view with three tabs; each tab triggering an activity
(In the doc I have read about ViewPager and fragments, but it is for a different purpose); if it is possible how can i do that ?
if it is not, must i break my app in three app ?
Thank you.

Comment: So what is the purpose?

Comment: Three different not linked apps under three different tabs. Fragments is not convenient because "fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle" (doc).

Answer (score 1):

Having activities in tabs has been deprecated as a technique for over five years.

Whether you use fragments or views for your `ViewPager` pages is up to you.

> if it is not, must i break my app in three app ?

No, you can have multiple fragments or multiple views within one app.

Comment: Multi fragments is not convenient because they are link together, the doc is clear on this point:"A fragment must always be embedded in an activity and the fragment's lifecycle is directly affected by the host activity's lifecycle. "That is the problem because when the activity's event starts, the fragment's event start too and I don't want it does; in summary, i wish to put three different not linked apps under three different tabs but maybe i am wrong...Could you be more specific about your multi views solution.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Make one activity with three tabs and one ViewPager. Each tab then change fragments in the ViewPager